# Kendo DataSource - update not called on DataSource.sync()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, kendo-ui, datasource, single-page-application

I have a Kendo UI Single Page Application. The 1st page of my application uses this template:

```
                <!-- App details -->
                <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="appDetails-template">
                    <div id="appSettings">
                         <input id="appName" type="text" placeholder="Your app title goes here" data-bind="value: appName" />
                         <input id="id" type="text" placeholder="id goes here" data-bind="value: id" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="button" value="Next" data-bind="click: showContactDetails" />
                    </div>
                </script>
```

I'm binding the view to a ViewModel like this:

```
kendo.bind($('#appSettings'), appSettingsViewModel);
```

I then specify the ViewModel, which includes a DataSource:

```
var appSettingsViewModel = kendo.observable({

appDetailsSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    autoSync: true,
    transport: {
        create: {
            url: appControllerUrl + "/SaveAppDetails",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: appControllerUrl + "/SaveAppDetails",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "post"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: { appName: { type: "string" } }
        }
    }
}),
showContactDetails: function (e) {
    this.appDetailsSource.sync();
    this.set("hasChanges", false);
}
});
```

If I provide valid values for 'appName' and 'id', then click the button, the showContactDetails method is called successfully, and appDetailsSource.sync() is called, however the update method doesn't seem to get called, and the server-side url that handles the update is never reached. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try use batch: true as [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sync) if it helps

Comment: There is no read method on datasource, so you are creating new item I guess. You need call datasource add to create new item and then call sync();